# Casting a NULL pointer function argument resulted in violation of Misra Rule 11.3

Tags: c, misra

I define a `NULL_PTR` as `0U`

Then call a function with this `NULL_PTR` as argument.

```
read_some_data(2U, (uint8_t *const) NULL_PTR, (uint8_t *const) NULL_PTR);
```

Called function prototype:

```
int16_t read_some_data(const uint8_t id,   uint8_t *const data_1, uint8_t *const data_2);
```

On compilation, Misra raised a rule 11.3 violation error.(A cast should not be performed between a pointer type and an integral type.)

But if I just pass the `NULL_PTR` as follows, no violation.

```
read_some_data(2U, NULL_PTR, NULL_PTR);
```

Which is the better way to do? Suppress Misra 11.3 rule or just pass the `NULL_PTR` without casting?

Comment: What is wrong with the Standard 'NULL'?

Comment: NULL_PTR should be defined as `(void *)0`. Note that this is different from C++, where you can just define it as `0`.

Comment: @Paul R. why? `0u` is a null pointer constant in both C and C++. `(void*)0` is a null pointer constant in C but not in C++. It's ambiguous in either whether `NULL_PTR` is intended to have pointer type, or to be a null pointer constant, so I've nothing *against* it being `(void*)0`, but presumably defining it that way will trigger the Misra rule and so is not an option here anyway. In C++ it pretty much *has* to be integer type to be useful, since there's no implicit conversion from `void*` to other pointer types, so `(void*)0` can't be assigned without a cast.

Comment: Does it trigger the Misra rule? C implementations are allowed to (and indeed often do) define `NULL` as `(void*)0`, which is a cast between pointer and integral types...

Comment: AFAIK, the main issue with it having integer type rather than pointer type is what happens when you foolishly use it in varargs without casting, because people wrongly think they know what type NULL has, and are more likely to wrongly think it's a pointer than to wrongly think it's specifically `int` as opposed to another integral type. If Misra bans casting, then you're pretty much screwed there, you'll have to create a temporary pointer variable to contain the value. The same would apply to unprototyped function calls, but surely Misra bans those too?

Comment: What kind of foolish rule is Misra 11.3 if it disallows `(void *)0` ? That expression is *guaranteed* to produce a *null pointer constant*.

Comment: MISRA does not ban casting - but 0u is not a pointer, it is an integral value.  @PaulR is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used NULL_PTR in my header file to avoid using IAR internal configuration file yvals.h which defines NULL. But that's not an issue since I may have to use yvals.h later due to other reasons.

Whether using NULL or NULL_PTR, I assume that the general consensus is to pass NULL without casting. My function doesn't have any problem in accepting it. This way, I can avoid suppressing Misra 11.3 rule.

Hope I am proceeding the right way.

Comment: I can't define NULL_PTR as (void*)0U since it again violates Misra rule 11.3. I left it 0U and passed the NULL_PTR with no cast.

Answer (score 2):

Why cast if you can avoid it? Cast always makes code a little bit more dirty and hints that there is something hacky performed.

So I would just pass NULL_PTR without casting. **After checking function specification** that it can accept NULL_PTR as its second parameter!!!

Answer (score 1):

> On compilation, Misra raised a rule 11.3 violation error.

Just to be pedantic, MISRA did not raise a violation error, your compiler raised a MISRA C:2004 rule violation error.

From what you've posted, I'm not convinced the reported violation is correct...

On the other hand, personally I'd define `NULL_PTR` as `(void *)0u` because (strictly speaking) 0 is not a pointer.

--

For MISRA C:2004, Rule 11.3 is *Advisory*, providing a recommendation... the Rule also says that this situation may be unavoidable.  As such, the violation may be ignored (with justification).  If applying MISRA Compliance, the Rule may be *disapplied*.

Alternatively, the equivalent guideline in the newer version, MISRA C:2012 Rule 11.4 has an explicit exception for a null pointer constant.